# CastError in with .findById()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cloud9-ide

I am just learning how to use MongoDB and trying to add a "show" page. My code all works except this one part. When I click on the link that should take me to the "show" page, I get this error:

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "(hex dec id here)" at path "_id"

This is the code I added to try to get the "show" page:

```
app.get("/homeowners/:id", function(req, res){
    Homeowner.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundHomeowner){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           res.render("show", {homeowner: foundHomeowner});
       }
    });
});
```

Can someone find what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) right? The value of `req.params.id` is not a valid [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/), hence the "cast error". You are probably trying an integer or a non-compliant string. If that was your intent then your schema definition is also wrong. If not your intent, then the id supplied is simply not valid. Rules in the link.

Comment: Ironically you obscured the actual value being sent in your question body. If you had left that in, you would get an immediate response telling you what to do. Since you "think" it's a hex value, then there might be the chance that you were previously playing with [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) and/or have some data from that source. The dead giveaway is present characters greater than `"f"`, which of course is as large as "hex" goes.

Comment: The actual value being sent is created by Mongo - I'm pretty sure its a hex value, but I could be wrong. The specific value changes depending on which link I click on, but they all give the same error.

Comment: For example, the link I just clicked gave me this value - 56eb186dce88277baf37f2aa

Comment: Sorry but what does *"the link I just clicked mean"*?  Do you mean that value shows in the error above? What we really need to see is the whole **un-edited** error being produced. The value you say you get is valid, but it's likely wrapped in other characters if producing this error. Also a good idea to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36097468/edit) your question to include the schema for this model.

Comment: @BlakesSeven { [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 56eb186dce88277baf37f2aa" at path "_id"]

message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 56eb186dce88277baf37f2aa" at path "_id"',

name: 'CastError',

kind: 'ObjectId',

value: ' 56eb186dce88277baf37f2aa',

path: '_id',

reason: undefined }

This is the EXACT error I get. If I click on a different link (this site is listing homeowners in the HOA, and each link is supposed to show more info on a particular homeowner), the hex dec id changes. Does that help?

Comment: There is a leading "space" in those values. See `" 56eb186dce88277baf37f2aa"`. Not sure how that is happening in `req.params.id`, but it is the cause of the error. You can sanitize with `req.params.id = req.params.id.trim()`

Comment: If indeed you are *"clicking this link"* then you should also look at how those links are being rendered. There is clearly whitespace or some other special character that is stripped preceeding the the `id` value. If the source of input is "hyperlinks", then there is a problem in their generation or data source.

Comment: Thank you! That space was indeed the problem!